# Removing Lists within Lists Efficiently in Python

Tags: python, list

Say you’ve got a list like `l=[[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[1,5,2],[4,2,1]]`, and you want to remove every list inside l that has 2 at index 1. What would be the most efficient way? At the moment I use a while loop that goes through each item and checks individually, however this uses up a large amount of CPU when the list becomes long. Is there a way that I could use the .remove() function to make this process easier?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `list comprehension` in order to filter your given list. List comprehension is an elegant way for transforming one list (any `iterable` actually) into another list.

```
list_updated = [item for item in l if item[1] != 2]
```

which is equivalent to.

```
result = []
for item in l:
  if item[1] != 2:
    result.append(item)
```

For big lists you can use a `generator comprehension`. A `generator` comprehension is the **lazy** version of a list comprehension.

```
list_updated = (item for item in l if item[1] != 2)
```

Using `generators` you can see the results using `next` method.

Comment: may be better to use generator comprehension for big datasets

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension to filter out the inner lists, then assign back to the original

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 5, 2], [4, 2, 1]]
>>> l = [i for i in l if i[1] != 2]
>>> l
[[1, 3, 4], [1, 5, 2]]
```

Comment: `l[:] =` to use the original list (not that it matters probably)